# Maui appicons incorrect on Android and iOS

Tags: svg, icons, maui

I am trying to set my appicon in a Maui project. My icon is an svg that is 420x420.

It is in my csproj file like this:

```
<!-- <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" Color="#512BD4" /> -->
<MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\logo_intro_icon.svg"  />
```

Note that I commented out the "default" icon the project template generated.

My AndroidManifest.xml looks like this (for the icon part):

```
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/logo_intro_icon" android:supportsRtl="true" android:label="InnerMonk"></application>
```

On windows, the app icon looks as expected. On Android, it is too large and forced to be round. On iOS, I am still getting the default project template icon and not my custom icon for my app.

This is built on .NET 7. Just for giggles - I created a .NET 8 project and just tried to replace the appicon on the default project the template generates - same issue.

I also tried renaming my icon to appicon.svg, cleaning and rebuilding. Exactly same behavior.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded a svg image and tested it on the Visual Studio Preview 17.8.0 Preview 5.0.

1. For the android, I can reproduce your problem. And according to the [official document about the android app icon in the maui](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/app-icons?tabs=android#adaptive-launcher), you can try to use `ForegroundScale="0.65"` such as:

```
<MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\logo_intro_icon.svg" ForegroundScale="0.65" />
```

2. For the iOS, I changed the value of [XSAppIconAssets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/app-icons?tabs=macios#platform-specific-configuration), such as:

```
<key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
<string>Assets.xcassets/logo_intro_icon.appiconset</string>
```

And the appicon changed successfully.

**Note:** I paired to Mac to test it on the ios and the environment on the Mac is : Visual Studio for Mac version 17.6 Preview  and XCode version 15.0.1.